# How to show looping result in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework2

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [phappointment_id] => 69
            [phc_id] => 49
            [valuator] => 91140961
            [valuated] => 87101133
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [phappointment_id] => 70
            [phc_id] => 49
            [valuator] => 98160588
            [valuated] => 87101133
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [phappointment_id] => 71
            [phc_id] => 49
            [valuator] => 91140961
            [valuated] => 89140962
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [phappointment_id] => 72
            [phc_id] => 49
            [valuator] => 98160588
            [valuated] => 94160284
        )
)
```

I loop that's array into this code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $dataValuated=$perf->loadValuated($post['valuate'][$i]['valuated']);
    $dataValuator=$perf->loadValuator($post['valuate'][$i]['valuator']);
}
$arrValuated=array();
$arrValuator=array();
foreach($dataValuator as $val){
   array_push($arrValuator, $val);
}
foreach($dataValuated as $val){
   array_push($arrValuated, $val);
}
```

But it when I got out the result, i just find 1 result, it must be 4 result.

echo json_encode(array('valuator'=>$arrValuator,'valuated'=>$arrValuated));

The result:

```
{"valuator":[{"valuator_name":"asad"}],"valuated":[{"valuated_name":"desan"}]}
```

How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Change  `$dataValuated[] =$perf->loadValuated($post['valuate'][$i]['valuated']);
    $dataValuator[]=$perf->loadValuator($post['valuate'][$i]['valuator']);` `dataValuated` and `dataValuator` should be array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you can create array `$arrValuated` and `$arrValuator` directly from `$post['valuate']`

```
<?php 
$arrValuated=array();
$arrValuator=array();

foreach($post['valuate'] as $valuate )
{
    $arrValuated[] = $perf->loadValuated($valuate['valuated']);
    $arrValuator[] = $perf->loadValuator($valuate['valuator']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Great glad to help you :) @NikeYulistiaAngreni can you please up vote my answer if it is helpful for you ;)

Comment: Thank You Dear @NikeYulistiaAngreni Ask anytime if you need any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably is because of missing [] behind of $dataValuated and $dataValuator in the for loop :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $dataValuated[]=$perf->loadValuated($post['valuate'][$i]['valuated']);
    $dataValuator[]=$perf->loadValuator($post['valuate'][$i]['valuator']);
}
```

Without [] it will always be one result by replacing the previous value with new one.

Comment: thank you, it was loop but how to show it? it return `{"valuator":[{},{},{},{}],"valuated":[{},{},{},{}]}`

Comment: what if you do this ? array('valuator'=>$dataValuator,'valuated'=>$dataValuated); because array_push is like unnecessary ?

Comment: then it seems like the $perf->loadValuated() and $perf->loadValuator() function did not return any value ? please check there.